# Asp.Net, textbox textchanged problem in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am having a problem when the textchanged event of the textbox object is triggered. For example, when I want to press the tab key, it should focus on the next object, but it does not. Or when I click a button, I have to click twice. How can I solve this? I added the codes and the problem I was having as a gif.

**default.aspx**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">İşlem Tutarı</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTutar" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm price" AutoPostBack="true" placeholder="0,00 ₺" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtTutar_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtTutar" EventName="TextChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

**default.asp.cs**

```
txtTahsilEdilen.Text = txtTutar.Text;
```

[image]

Comment: You can dump the trigger - it will do nothing of value for you. You need to set AutoPostBack="true" for that text box - and the trigger will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the trigger - it will do nothing of value for you. You need to set AutoPostBack="true" for that text box - and the trigger will not help you.

Then what on earth is the trigger for then?

It is used to trigger ANOTHER SEPERATE panel on the same page!!!

So, you can have a button in a panel, even a text box. They STILL MUST do a post back here - and you need/have to add the post-back to the text box.

What the triggers do? Well, say you have a 2nd update panel - and has a bunch of things in it. Well, your code behind might update BOTH panels.

Hence, you would add a trigger to the 2nd panel that points to your text box (or button in the first panel). Now when that first panel update panel updates (due to a post-back), the 2nd panel with the trigger tag and settings will ALSO refresh.

However, the FEATURE DOES NOT AUTO POST back for you. So specifying a trigger into the SAME update panel is not required, does not make sense, and will do NOTHING at all for you.

Unless a post back IS TRIGGERED then the trigger settings do nothing at all, and they do not cause a post back, and they do not case the button code, or in this case the text box event code to run.

So, the triggers settings would in theory be placed in a 2nd and different update panel that you want to also re-fresh when one button (or text box) cases a post-back in the other update panel. However for this to work, YOU STILL MUST cause and have a post-back to occur.

So the purpose here is to not make the update panel post-back, but only to detect that a ANOTHER DIFFERENT panel REALLY DID JUST do a postback.

No matter which way we note and explain the above?

The trigger settings does NOT trigger the button or text box post-back - that is your job to make that occur. the trigger setting in the update panel can thus be set that some post back by a given button occurred, and then ensure that the panel with the trigger will also update. But for the same panel - there is no practical meaning or reason to do this, since the trigger tags only EVER work WHEN you cause a post-back. And the trigger settings are to ONLY point to buttons or controls in a DIFFERENT update panel.

Bottom line:
Remove the trigger tag - don't need it.

Set the text box to have auto postback = true

Comment: I already set autopostback=true at the textbox. And i removed the triggers. It's still not working. Honestly, I didn't understand much of what you wrote. My English is not very good. Can you give an example with code?

Comment: Really simple - if you set autopost-back = true for that text box, then if you edit and tab out, then it will fire the text changed - that's all you need to know. As noted, you can remove the trigger markup you have - it not required. So really that's all you need to know here.